# Testimonial slider with object constructor

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have the first testimonial shown when you land on the page without hard coding it in the html.  I want the page to land on the first customers object when run.

When this loops over the customers object it doesn't include the hard coded html elements. So I would like it to just have the object constructed shown when the code is run. Obviously I am having trouble forming this question and therefore finding a solution.

```js
(function(){
    const customerImage = document.querySelector('#customer-img')
    const customerName = document.querySelector('#customer-name')
    const customerText = document.querySelector('#customer-text')
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
    let index = 0
    const customers = []

    //Create a new customer using a customer constructor
    
    //Customer Constructor
    function Customer(img, name, text) {
        this.img = img
        this.name = name
        this.text = text
    }

    //Create new customer using the constructor function

    function createCustomer(img, name, text) {

        let fullImg = `./img/customer-${img}.jpg`
        let customer = new Customer(fullImg, name, text)

        customers.push(customer)
    }

    
    createCustomer(0, 'John', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis neque reprehenderit laborum, corporis explicabo assumenda. Porro impedit consectetur animi, reprehenderit recusandae sapiente at aliquam reiciendis modi ipsam rerum suscipit distinctio?')
    createCustomer(1, 'Sandy', 'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock')
    createCustomer(2, 'Amy', 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don\'t look even slightly believable.')
    createCustomer(3, 'Tyrell', 'If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn\'t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.')
    createCustomer(4, 'Wanda', 'Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.')
    

    buttons.forEach(function(button){
        button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('prevBtn')){
               if(index === 0){
                    index = customers.length
               }
               index--
               customerImage.src = customers[index].img
               customerName.textContent = customers[index].name
               customerText.textContent = customers[index].text
            }
            if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('nextBtn')){
                index++
                if(index === customers.length){
                     index = 0
                }
                customerImage.src = customers[index].img
                customerName.textContent = customers[index].name
                customerText.textContent = customers[index].text
             }
        })
    })
    
})()
```

```css
.max-height{
 min-height: 100vh;
 background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)) ,url('../img/questionBcg.jpeg')center/cover no-repeat fixed;
}
.title-heading{
 color:#f15025;
}
.title-subheading{
 color: white;
}
.customer-card{
 background: transparent!important;
 color:white;
 border:0.05rem solid white;
 padding-bottom: 1rem;
 padding-left: 1rem;
 padding-right: 1rem;
 position: relative;
}
.img-card{
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
 margin-top: -3rem;
}
.star-icon{
 color: #f15025;
}
.quote-icon{
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: #f15025;
}
.prevBtn,.nextBtn{
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 padding: 0.1rem;
 color:#f15025;
 border:0.1rem solid #f15025;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 0.4rem;
 border-radius: 50%;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.prevBtn:hover{
background: #f15025;
color: white;

}
.nextBtn:hover{
background: #f15025;
color: white;

}
.prevBtn{
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 transform: translate(-120%,-50%);
}
.nextBtn{
 top: 50%;
 right: 0;
 transform: translate(120%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <!-- bootstrap css -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- main css -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 <!-- google fonts -->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- font awesome -->
 <script src="js/all.js"></script>
 <title>Starter Template</title>
 <style>
 </style>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row max-height align-items-center">
   <!-- col -->
   <div class="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col text-center my-5">
      <h4 class="title-heading text-uppercase">client</h4>
      <h1 class="title-subheading text-uppercase">testimonials</h1>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card my-5 text-center customer-card ">
     <img src="img/customer-0.jpg" width="150" id="customer-img" class="img-card mx-auto" alt="">
     <h4 id="customer-name" class="text-uppercase">John</h4>
     <div class="review-icons my-2">
      <span class="star-icon">
       <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="star-icon">
       <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="star-icon">
       <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="star-icon">
       <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="star-icon">
       <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
      </span>
     </div>
     <p id="customer-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis neque reprehenderit laborum, corporis explicabo assumenda. Porro impedit consectetur animi, reprehenderit recusandae sapiente at aliquam reiciendis modi ipsam rerum suscipit distinctio?</p>
     <span class="quote-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i>
     </span>
     <a href="#" class="btn prevBtn"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
     <a href="#" class="btn nextBtn"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!-- end of col -->
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I was thinking about using the following code document.addEventListener('open', a =>){
        createCustomer(0);
    }

Comment: document.addEventListener('open', a =>){
        index === 0
        customerImage.src = customers[index].img
        customerName.textContent = customers[index].name
        customerText.textContent = customers[index].text
    }

Answer (score 0):

I put this iffe function at the beginning to fix this problem.

```js
(function(){
    var img = document.getElementById('customer-img').src = 'img/customer-0.jpg';
    var name = document.getElementById("customer-name")
    name.innerHTML = "John";
    var text = document.getElementById("customer-text")
    text.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis neque reprehenderit laborum, corporis explicabo assumenda. Porro impedit consectetur animi, reprehenderit recusandae sapiente at aliquam reiciendis modi ipsam rerum suscipit distinctio?";
})();
```